# wire click livewire method responds slowly when there are other methods that have larger processing data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9, laravel-livewire-wireclick

I'm using livewire v2. I have a problem when calling a method in livewire feels slow because another method has a large data process, for example I have 2 methods. the first method is called `methodSmallData()` and the second method is `methodLargeData()`.

The code example is as below:

This is controller livewire Show.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\SomeController;

class Show extends Component
{

public function render(){

$smallData = $this->methodSmallData();
$largeData = $this->methodLargeData();

return view('path_view',compact('smallData ','largeData '));

}

public function methodSmallData(){
dd('test how long this dd is displayed');
return Products::all();
}

public function methodLargeData(){

return LargeProducts::all();
}

}
```

This is view component of livewire show.blade.php

```
<div>
  <button wire:click='methodSmallData'>Small Data Product</button>
  <button wire:click='methodLargeData'>LargeData Product</button>
</div>
```

when I run it the **first time** there is no problem and the dd() function immediately displays the message in it, but when I click the button the **second time** and so on I get a long delay of about 23 seconds to be able to display the message in the dd() function in the method `methodSmallData()`.

I want to prioritize the `methodSmallData()` method to run without waiting for the `methodLargeData()` method to finish so that the `methodSmallData()` method can directly hit dd() without having to delay or wait for the `methodLargeData()` method to finish. the point is I don't want to be made into 1 load of the same data even though it has different values, so it is more structured that has small data can be completed first without having to wait together.

I tried to remove `methodLargeData()` in `reder()` and it successfully displayed the dd() message without any delay. but the problem is I can't access `methodLargeData()` because I might give the data some filters so I put it in the `render()` method.

Comment: When you click a button, the related method is executed first, then *render()* is also executed, and finally the response is sent to the browser (including the various *dd()*). Therefore the time spent executing the method is added to the time spent calling *methodSmallData()* and *methodLargeData()*. I don't think it's possible to send a response from the backend before all the processing is complete.

Comment: You can skip render https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/actions#skipping-re-renders - but like Pippo said, `render()` is called at the end of every request, where you have your expansive query, so it will run every time. Consider caching is also an option.